# how to read broken numbers on two lines in a text file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

how to read broken numbers on two lines in matlab?

I am generating some results in text files that are being broken into two lines. Example:

```
text x = 1.
2345 text
```

What would a code look like to read the value x = 1.2345?

Suppose the value of `x = 1.2345` is in file named *name.txt*.

When it doesn't break the values I'm looking for:

```
text x = 1.2345 text
```

I use the following (working) code:

```
buffer = fileread('name.txt') ;
search = 'x = ' ;
local = strfind(buffer, search);
xvalue = sscanf(buffer(local(1,1)+numel(search):end), '%f', 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove line breaks (and other "white space", if needed) before parsing the string:

```
>> str = sprintf('text x = 1.\n2345 text')

str =
  'text x = 1.
   2345 text'


>> str = regexprep(str, '\n', '')

str =
  'text x = 1.2345 text'
```